# JavaScript: Finding the number regular expression matches

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

In JavaScript, I'm using the global flag on a regular expression to replace a string. The code is as follows.

```
var string = "$$";
string = string.replace(/\$+/g, '"\'$$\'"');
```

The code above will replace any occurrence of `$` with the new string `"'$$'"`.

Is it possible to get the number of occurrences of the matched `$`? For example, I would like to replace `$$$$` with `"'$$$$$$$$'"`. In order to do that, I would need to know that there were four occurrences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can capture the number of `$` and replace with it twice:

```
string = string.replace(/\$+/g, '"\'$&$&\'"');
```

The `$&` replaces what was captured.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function instead of a string for the second parameter in the replace method like so:

```
var string = '$$';

string = string.replace(/(\$+)/g, function(match, $1) { return $1+$1; })
```

for more information on the replace method visit

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace